# Find out what Controller is triggering an event in symfony2

Tags: events, symfony, triggers, controller

I need to trigger an event ONCE in my symfony2 project for each web
i have created an event that is dispatched whenever kernel.controller occurs, the problem is that this makes the event run six or seven times and I only want it to run once.

any ideas or suggestions?

if so,I wouldn't mind being able to know what controller triggered the event so I can put the code I want to put there!!

Comment: Can you explain better what you are trying to accomplish here?

Comment: I'm trying to set the language of the website.

Comment: so what I basically need is just a simple way of , before twig starts rendering anything, insert my code that will check some variables and will end up doing  $this->get('session')->setLocale($lang);